# jquery sortable event trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list of items in a div that can be moved to another list with jquery sortable. This is my html:

```
        <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue">
        <span>MyPage disponibili</span>
    <?php $i = 0; foreach($clocks as $clock) { ?>
            <li class="percheckbox clock ui-state-default" id="orologio_<?php echo $clock['id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $clock['nome']; ?>
            </li>
    <?php $i += 1; } ?>
        </ul>
        <ul id="sortable4" class="droptrue">
        <span>MyPage selezionati</span>
        </ul>
```

So the user can move items from #sortable2 to #sortable4.
I would like to apply some css to another div in the dom when the user has moved at least one item from #sortable2 to #sortable4. I have tried to look for what kind of event I should look at (change, blur, ecc) but couldn't find an answer to my question.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can use the receive event for that!

From the [documentation of the receive event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive):

> This event is triggered when an item from a connected sortable list has been dropped into another list. The latter is the event target.

So you could do something like that:

```
$( "#sortable4" ).sortable({
    receive: function( event, ui ) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the Jquery Ui Sortable API and the events there
http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update

Eg you can look for the update event on the sortable4 target:

```
$( "#sortable4" ).sortable({
   update: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```